# Weird performace with VirtIO adapter in Linux Guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, yum, centos7, virtio

I have been battling an extremely odd behavior with the VirtIO adapter for Linux KVM guests. First, my set up:

KVM host is a CentOS 6.8 box. Guests are running CentOS 7. The adapters were originally connected to a host bridge although I changed the virtual networking into a OVS setup with the guests connecting to a OVS bridge.

The Linux guests all live on the OVS bridge "internalbr1" that is not bridged to a host interface. Instead, traffic goes to the LAN gateway of 10.255.0.1 which is the LAN interface of a PFSense VM who sends it out through a passthrough interface on the host. Basically the OVS bridge "internalbr1" is acting as a switch between the guests and firewall LAN side.

Originally the guests had the e1000 adapter but due to speed issues (speed decrease down to 100k during downloads) I want to switch over to VirtIO. There is a Windows Guest (2012) running with a VirtIO adapter (saw same e1000 issue. On a bridge to a host interface) and it's working perfectly. All of the Linux guests can ping out just fine with no latency, trying to pull web pages with wget is extremely slow and yum commands return with "No route to host" even though pings to the yum repos work just fine.

I'm at a loss on what's going on and hours googling is not helping. Has anyone else ran into an issue similar before?

**Update**

Discovered that it was the PfSense firewall after all and not VirtIO (well partially). After doing some packet captures on the firewall I discovered bad checksums on the packets leaving. I found that this is sometimes the issue with hardware checksum offloading. I disabled hardware checksum offloading and everything starting working like it should. I guess the VirtIO adapter cannot do hardware checksum offloading (at least with my versions). This also explained why I was seeing no issue with the e1000 adapter.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Why do you think this is a virtio_net issue? I'd start with connecting a VM directly to the outside network and verifying it's not the firewall, maybe even dump OVS and use a regular bridge instead

Comment: These troubled guests were on a regular bridge to begin with and had the same issue. And I've ruled out the host firewall as the Windows guest has no issues. Even the e1000 works although is just slow (Windows guest had the same issue). I'll try adding a NIC to Windows guest and change it to go out the 10.255.0.1 firewall to rule out it being an issue as well. Will update soon with results.

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2016-March/msg00034.html